# XQuartz opens automatically: How can I track this?

Tags: emacs, xquartz

From time to time Xquartz opens without any application being called. Is this some virus that tries to exploit bugs in x11? Is it gnu emacs that was not fully ported and calls X stuff?

Comment: It could be a number of things, but I doubt it's Emacs. I haven't used Aquamacs or Carbon Emacs, but the regular GNU Emacs.app available from http://emacsformacosx.com/ doesn't call out to X11; the one in Homebrew can be configured to use X11, but doesn't by default.

Comment: Also, normally Xquartz only launches if an app tries to connect to its socket, which is given by your `$DISPLAY` variable. That should look something like `/tmp/launch-4e5sj8/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`.